# Capybara debug, don't even know where has this error

Tags: debugging, capybara

I am debugging, then the error message pop up like following:

```
http://127.0.0.1:56121/apps/quicktip/quicktip_model.js|84|=============================checkShownBefore 
Started request to "http://127.0.0.1:56121/apps/quicktip/ejs/quicktip.ejs" 
Received 200 from "http://127.0.0.1:56121/apps/quicktip/ejs/quicktip.ejs" 
http://127.0.0.1:56121/apps/quicktip/quicktip_model.js|31|=============_setTip 
http://127.0.0.1:56121/apps/quicktip/quicktip_controller.js|153|======================currentTip 
http://127.0.0.1:56121/apps/quicktip/quicktip_controller.js|153|==============finish currentTip 
http://127.0.0.1:56121/apps/quicktip/quicktip_model.js|31|=============_setTip 
http://127.0.0.1:56121/apps/quicktip/quicktip_controller.js|153|======================currentTip 
http://127.0.0.1:56121/apps/quicktip/quicktip_controller.js|153|==============finish currentTip 
undefined|0|TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function
```

It didn't even mention which file is complaining the type error, I tried to use `console.log` in `quicktip_controller.js`, to see whether there is anything wrong after this page. But I can get nothing. Any suggestion??

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion is that the `undefined` is valid in [js](/questions/tagged/js), but invalid for pure [rails](/questions/tagged/rails) environment. So you haveto look into **apps/quicktip/ejs/quicktip.ejs** or around files for the occurines of `undefined` keyword in [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) code.